# How many students are not enrolled in any of these three courses?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

55 people are enrolled in courses of the Diploma of Information Technology. While 35 are registered in OOP, 23 in BD, 27 in SAP, 15 in OOP and SAP, 9 in SAP and BD, 12 in OOP courses and BD and, finally, 4 are enrolled in the three courses, how many people are not enrolled in any of these three courses?

**My attempt:**  $55−(((35−(15+12))+(27−(15+9))+(23−(12+9)))+(12+15+9))=2$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  For an exercise such as this, you should explain what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses appropriate to your skill level.

Comment: i found the answer is 2. I would like to know if it s the right answer

Comment: You are correct.  You should edit your question (click on the edit button at the bottom of your post) to explain your reasoning.

Comment: 55−(((35−(15+12))+(27−(15+9))+(23−(12+9)))+(12+15+9))=2

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

Let $O$ denote the set of students enrolled in $OOP$; let $B$ denote the number of students enrolled in $BD$; let $S$ denote the number of students enrolled in $SAP$.  The [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) states that the number of students taking at least one of the three courses is 
$$|O \cup B \cup S| = |O| + |B| + |S| - |O \cap B| - |O \cap S| - |B \cap S| + |O \cap B \cap S|$$
Hence, the number of students enrolled in at least one of the courses is 
$$|O \cup B \cup S| = 35 + 23 + 27 - 12 - 15 - 9 + 4 = 53$$
Therefore, the number of students enrolled in none of these courses is 
$$|O^C \cap B^C \cap S^C| = |U| - |O \cup B \cup C| = 55 - 53 = 2$$

Comment: Very clear. Thanks.